# MySQL keys for GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

Table structure, indexes, and query are below. On a table with more than million records, this takes well over a minute to run. I guess mainly because of GROUP BY and / or DAY().

I tried creating a composite index with the draft column first, because that would allow faster querying of WHERE draft = 0. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference and I haven't been able to find much information at all on how to use indexes to optimise this kind of query with a GROUP BY.

How can I speed this up?

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `coords` point NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `draft` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `table`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `draft` (`draft`),
  ADD KEY `date` (`date`),
  ADD KEY `user_id_2` (`draft`,`user_id`,`date`) USING BTREE;


SELECT id, user_id, date, coords
FROM table
WHERE draft = 0
GROUP BY (user_id, DAY(date))
ORDER BY date ASC

EXPLAIN

select type: simple
table: table
type: ref
possible_keys: draft, user_id_2
key: draft
key_len: 1,
ref: const
rows: 3427592
extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: Note that in the absence of of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. So get rid of that. Also, get rid of the draft index, and rearrange the user_id2 index as (draft,date,user_id)

Comment: I think that adding a functional index by day with  `ADD KEY user_id_2 (draft,user_id,DAY(date))` rather than simply `date` might help

Comment: Your query makes no sense - it will output ANY (some randomly selected) `id`, `date` and `coords` values from all available for each group with the same  `user_id, DAY(date)`. When query's result makes no sense then its optimization makes no sense too....

Comment: @Akina thanks for pointing out this issue, I'll have to go back and amend my query.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see any reason why you are even using `GROUP BY`, given that your select clause does not include any aggregates.  Perhaps this is what you are intending to run:

```
SELECT id, user_id, date, coords
FROM yourTable
WHERE draft = 0
ORDER BY date;
```

This query might benefit from the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (draft, date);
```

If used, this index would let MySQL discard some records via the `WHERE` clause, and also would enable efficient sorting in the `ORDER BY date` clause.  You could also go all out, and cover the select clause:

```
    CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (draft, date, user_id);
```

This would cover the entire select clause, meaning that the index by itself would contain all information needed to complete the query (this assumes you are running InnoDB, in which case MySQL would automatically include `id` as the fourth column of the index).

Comment: The GROUP BY is required to get 1x record per user per day. Your query would get all records where draft is zero. Perhaps I should use DISTINCT?

Comment: ...and what is the logic to determine _which_ 1 distinct record gets selected?  You haven't told us this.